# Shell script without using sudo in ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, shell, ubuntu, vagrant

Totally new to shell script's and I have a script that execute the following command in order to export my database from `Vagrant`:

```
export_folder="/var/www/projects/DatabaseBackup/local"

schema="wp"

tables="wp_8_options"

export_data="mysqldump -uroot -pmy-secret-password --opt $schema $tables > $file_name.sql"

sudo vagrant ssh --command "cd $export_folder && $export_data"
```

`$export_folder` : *Is the path inside Vagrant, that corresponding on my host computer folder*

`$scema` : *The database to export from Vagrant mySql server*

`$tables` : *The tables to export from the selected schema*

`$export_data` : *The actual mysqldump command that exporting the data*

`sudo vagrant ssh --command "..."` : *The command that instruct the Vagrant to use the SSH in order to execute another command inside the Vagrant VM*.

All the code above, run's from a shell script and until now it works properly. The reason I have write this script is to automate the database exporting when ever I commit something on my `Git` by using the `Git` hooks.

The problem with the above script, is that I cannot run it via the `Git` hooks, because it is using `sudo`.

Unfortunatelly the `Vagrant` requires `sudo` on my computer in order to get run. Also, you should know, that I am not a `Vagrant` expert, and the `Vagrant` got installed on my computer by another coworker, so I don't know how to modify it in order to run without `sudo`.

Additionally, I don't really care about this script security because will only run from inside my computer.

So the question is, how to run this script, without using the `sudo` command. What are the options for that ?

Comment: Why does Vagrant require `sudo`? I am using it on Ubuntu and it worked without `sudo` out of the box. Did you install it in some weird way? Or perhaps initially create the Vagrant VM as `root`?

Comment: I don't really know !! :) I have not install it. It got installed by another coworker. I am totally new on Vagrant. The only think that I know is that requires always sudo to run anything. I use sudo for vagrant up, vagrant halt, vagrant ssh, ....

Comment: Maybe exists a group for using "Vagrant". This is just an hypothesis, I just checked what Vagrant is, looks like a VM (am I right?). Check with `cat /etc/group` if there's a vagrant group. If so add your user to the group.

Comment: No there is not exists. The only that exists is `vboxusers:x:126:` that maybe is for the VirtualBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give yourself power to `sudo vagrant` without a password:

Your /etc/sudoers file will have to include the line

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

you **must** use the `visudo` command to edit /etc/sudoers -- **do not** edit it manually.

Then, `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/<username>` and add to that file

```
<username> <hostname> = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vagrant
```

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution. It's probably still a good idea to figure out what's wrong with Vagrant and fix the cause, not the symptom.